# why is the google map variable inaccessible?

Tags: google-maps, coffeescript, scope

I have the following code in my js file

```
$(document).ready ->
  mapOptions = null
  map = null
  set_user_location = (position) ->
    mapOptions =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
      zoom: 14
  console.log mapOptions
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions)
```

The value of mapOptions variable is null when I look it up in the console.
Am I missing something obvious here?. Please help.

Comment: if navigator.geolocation
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(set_user_location,error)

Comment: position is the variable being passed by the browser to set_user_location method

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` runs asynchronously, initialize the map in `set_user_location` or initialize the map outside `set_user_location` with a default-`center` and assign a new `center` in `set_user_location`

Comment: Hmm..My point is that I want to make the map varible global so that all my functions can access it since my application is pretty map intensive..Can you suggest a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with coffeescript, but AFAIK the map-variable will be global when you declare it in global scope(outside `$(document).ready`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `map` to be global then you have to manually attach it to `window` (assuming that you're in a browser):

```
window.map = null
$(document).ready ->
  # use `window.map` in here...
```

or like this:

```
@map = null
$(document).ready ->
  #...
```

You'll have to be very careful about how you reference `map` though or CoffeeScript will think you want a local variable; for example, this won't do what you might think:

```
@map = null
$(document).ready ->
  map = something
```

That will make a local `map` variable inside the callback function so the global `map` won't get touched.

If you want a global then I'd recommend setting up a global application-specific namespace:

```
# Somewhere before anything else happens...
@your_app_name = { }
```

and then make anything global be a property in your namespace:

```
$(document).ready ->
  your_app_name.map = null
  #...
```

Now you always have to include the full namespace (which helps avoid naming conflicts) and you won't have to worry too much about CoffeeScript getting confused about when you want a local variable versus a global one.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation..helped alot.